# Browserstack runs does not update its capabilities

Tags: cucumber, capybara, browserstack

I was wondering if anyone else knows a good way to start individual browser stack tests sequentially using Capybara/Browserstack/Cucumber.

I'm having issues with using Capybara in the sense that browserstack doesn't get updated with my new capabilities for every run, even when I shut down my browser, i.e: The two test runs are started sequentually in Browserstack, but with the same browser and OS-settings.

Abstract Scenario: Run login tests
 Given that I want to test x website with capabilities     og 
    Examples:
      |browser|browser_version|   os      |os_version|resolution|
      |IE|    11.0       | Windows        |8.1        |1024x768  |
      |Firefox|    45.0       | Windows   |10        |1024x768  |

I've checked that every value successfully gets sent through to the next step, but it seems like Browserstack doesn't update its new capabilities that I'm trying to set.

I know I can probably manage to do parallell runs setting capabilities through settings instead, but we have a limit to how many parallell runs using Browserstack's license. That's why I want to run them sequantually and figured this could be a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, BrowserStack initiates a test on a particular OS/browser capability that it receives from your tests. Thus, it seems your setup is sending the same capability for both the runs of the test.

I believe you want to run tests sequentially and on different OS/browser combinations. In that case you can refer to the BrowserStack's documentation for configuring [Parallel Cucumber tests using Rake file](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/ruby#cucumber) in the "Parallel tests" section. After creating all the files, you can run the following command to run tests sequentially:

```
rake BS_USERNAME=<username> BS_AUTHKEY=<access_key> nodes=1
```